# Html.DropDownListFor Selected=true reset automatically in index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’m binding `@html.DropdownListFor` control via modal in mvc page.

My code as below in cshtml page,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.stateId, Model.statelist, new { @id = "StateList", @class = "form-control" })
```

in above Model.Statelist is of type `List<SelectListItem>`

I checked the Model.statelist have 2nd item Selected=true by debugging code.

But after render page on browser, selecteditem goes to first item.

Can any one Suggest me.

Comment: What did you exactly assign to Model.statelist? can you share your action method or part of it?

Comment: public List<SelectListItem> stateList(Int32 stateId)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> state_List = new List<SelectListItem>();
            state_List = db.tbl_states.Where(a => a.state_id != 8).Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = a.name,
                Value = a.state_id.ToString(),
                Selected = a.state_id == stateId ? true : false
            }).ToList();
            state_List.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "0", Selected = false });
            return state_List;
        }

Comment: As you're using DropDownListFor, no need to assign Id. Is possible to have 2 options with value =0? Your option with Text=All will ever get selected?

Comment: Yes, Dropdown first index item which value has 0 is selected on page Rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the following change. I did notice, for first parameter you have used 'a', while for second parameter list you have have "Model".

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.stateId, model.statelist, new { @id = "StateList", @class = "form-control" })
```